# Error in computing contours in R

Tags: r, contour

I am trying to generate contours for a LST (Land Surface Temperature) file using R

```
lst<-raster("test_lst.tif")
cl <- contourLines(lst,20)
shp <- ContourLines2SLDF(cl)
```

However, I get the error that

> Error in contourLines(lst, 20) : no proper 'z' matrix specified

I understand that the command needs `x`, `y` (the coordinates) and `z` (in this case the LST values). However, I am not able to put my data in this format. I tried converting my file to matrix using `as.matrix`, however the problem still remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though `contourLines` did not work for me, but I used `rasterToContour` and it worked perfectly.

`cnt <- rasterToContour(lst)
writeOGR(cnt, "lst_contour", layer="cnt", driver="ESRI Shapefile")`